# Function not returning string

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

So I'm getting back to programming and I'm having an issue. My function is not returning a value when I'm storing a Value in it. Could you guys have a look and point my out why that is happening?

```
func getLocation() -> NSString {
    manager = OneShotLocationManager()
    var tempLocation: NSString = "" // created an empty string for the var

    manager!.fetchWithCompletion {location, error in
        if let locatie = location {
            tempLocation = String(locatie.coordinate.latitude) + "," + String(locatie.coordinate.longitude)
            print(tempLocation) // It stores a value here but will not show it on the return
        } else if let err = error {
            tempLocation = err.localizedDescription
        }
        self.manager = nil
    }
    return tempLocation // It's not returning anything here.. 
}
```

Comment: What is the function returning?  What should it to return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything so just "", as it should need to return one of the two things in doing in the middle of the function

Comment: I noticed you are using `NSString` vs. `String`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The completion starts after you exit the function, so that is the problem i guess. You return "" and then do the stuff inside completion code

Comment: Is there a way to first do the completion and then the return?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is not possible. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not returning the value because the `fetchWithCompletion` is being executed after the return statement as it is asynchronous. You can amend your function by using a completion handler to get access the `tempLocation` once it has been set:

```
func getLocation(completion: (location: String) -> ())  {
    manager = OneShotLocationManager()
    var tempLocation: NSString = "" // created an empty string for the var

    manager!.fetchWithCompletion {location, error in
        if let locatie = location {
            tempLocation = String(locatie.coordinate.latitude) + "," + String(locatie.coordinate.longitude)
            print(tempLocation) // It stores a value here but will not show it on the return
        } else if let err = error {
            tempLocation = err.localizedDescription
        }
        self.manager = nil
        completion(location: tempLocation)
    }
}
```

You can implement this function in the following way:

```
getLocation { (location) -> () in
    print(location)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call getLocation and do your stuff inside the fetchWithCompletion closure

```
func getLocation() {
    manager = OneShotLocationManager()

    manager!.fetchWithCompletion {location, error in
        if let locatie = location {
            tempLocation = String(locatie.coordinate.latitude) + "," + String(locatie.coordinate.longitude)

            //DO THE THINGS YOU NEED TO DO WITH THE LOCATION HERE

        } else if let err = error {
            tempLocation = err.localizedDescription
        }
        self.manager = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closure provided to `fetchWithCompletion()` is called asynchronously - upon the completion of the manager's location fetch.  Your function starts the manager fetching and then returns before the manager's fetch is complete; thus the initial assignment to `tempLocation` is return as `""`.

As the fetch is asynchronous, perhaps your `getLocation()` should also be asynchronous?

```
func getLocationAsynch (handler: (String) -> Void) {
  OneShotLocationManager()!.fetchWithCompletion { location, error in
    if let locatie = location {
      handler (String(locatie.coordinate.latitude) + "," + String(locatie.coordinate.longitude))
    } else if let err = error {
      handler (err.localizedDescription)
    } else {
      handler ("")
    }
  }
}
```

The above prevents your code from blocking; perhaps when the location becomes available you just display it for the user?

If, however, you want to block.  Use a `dispatch_semaphore` as:

```
// assuming dispatch_semaphore works in Swift
func getLocation () -> String {
  let sem = dispatch_semaphore_create (0);
  var result = ""

  OneShotLocationManager()!.fetchWithCompletion { location, error in
    if let locatie = location {
      result = String(locatie.coordinate.latitude) + "," + String(locatie.coordinate.longitude)
    } else if let err = error {
      result = err.localizedDescription
    } 
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem)
  }

  dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem)
  return result
}
```